# TestNG test not running via command line

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have been following instructions to create a pom.xml file and testng.xml file which references the correct test class but it does not seem to work/find the test.

My pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        .........
        .........
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
```

My testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="src.Schoology"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The test itself is found at:

**folderRoot < restassured < src < Schoology**

When I try to run the test using the command:

```
mvn test -Dtest="restassured.src.Schoology"
```

I get the following error:

**No tests matching pattern "restassured.src.Schoology" were executed! (Set -Dsurefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]**

I thought the testng.xml file was set up properly so I'm not really sure why it can't find the class. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Also, the structure of the project is shown here:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This `<class name="src.Schoology"/>` looks strange. Can you show your folder structure in IDE?

Comment: Hi, I added a pic of the structure above. Thanks

Comment: What surefire plugin version do you use?

Comment: ```
 <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
```

Comment: testing file should be located in `src/test/java/<package>/` and follow Naming conventions unit tests like `*Test.java` no need to define the includes for surefire plugin (that's the default)... no manual binding via execution block neccessary... also use most recent version of surefire plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) and do not use suite files for testng better follow naming convention... the question is also if you really need testng ...maybe a better way would be to use JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) etc...

Answer (score 0):

Your test files must be located under the `src/test` package. This is the default path maven test plugin is looking for all the test files.

Comment: Is the structure in the picture I added in incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You have really messy and misleading folder structure. First of all, when you run test as `mvn test -Dtest="restassured.src.Schoology"` you basically ignore your `testng.xml` configuration.

The next thing is that `restassured` is not a part of your package name. It is a *test resource folder*. You mark it as *test resource folder* in your IDE but when you run it from command line maven has no idea about it needs to take classes from that folder to the *classpath*.

To fix the last issue you need to add `<testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/restassured</testSourceDirectory>` to `<build>...</build>` part of your `pom.xml`

Now you can run your test but still have to remove `restassured.` from your fully qualified class name. So your call would look like this:

`mvn test -Dtest="src.Schoology"`

**P.S.** - do not forget to do `clean` before your trial.

Comment: Thank you, where abouts would this go in the pom?

Comment: you can put `<testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/restassured</testSourceDirectory>` right under `<build>` line. If I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Inside maven surefire plugin:

```
<configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                                <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                            <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/restassured</testSourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
```

Comment: Or at the top of the <build>, like this:

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/restassured</testSourceDirectory>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <plugins>

Comment: Hi, an update:

I have added the class to src/test/java and renamed as "SchoologyTest". The testng.xml file also reflects this.

When I run " mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml
" it runs the other existing tests but does not run this test. Do you know why

Comment: You should raise another question on that. There is too much details required to discuss in comments.